# A post-answer modification to a question be put under a heading "Post Script"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After an OP has asked a question, he could modify the question.

In some cases, I find, after the question has been answered, the question is modified by the OP in the light of the answer. After the question is so modified, the answer (which prompted the OP to modify the question) becomes unmeaning. Those who visit the question post-modification find the answer unmeaning, without realising that it is the answer that has caused the question to be modified and that the answer has become unmeaning only because the answer itself has prompted the question to be modified.

To remedy the situation and to ensure the answerer is not in a poor light before those who visit the question post-modification, can I suggest that a post-answer modification to the question be put under a heading "Post Script"?

Answer (score 2):

In general on SE, these sorts of modifications are *discouraged*, precisely because they invalidate answers! Instead, the usual advice is to ask a new question.

Here, questions are often rather muddled to begin with, so there's a bit more leeway, but an edit that really substantially changes the question is still dubious. There is certainly no reason to modify the software to make that problem *easier to run into*.

Finally, the philosophy on SE is to make sure all posts are displayed in a complete, polished form, without "EDIT 2:", "UPDATE:", "[SOLVED]", "POST-ANSWER POSTSCRIPT:" and the like. There should be a cleaned-up question, and straightforward answers. The rest goes into revision histories.

Answer (score 1):

This does happen every once in a while on SE.

If you notice this, my recommendation is to leave a comment under the answer – something along the lines of:

> NOTE: this answer was written before the question was edited, and the answer appears to answer an [earlier version of the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/b6d4c1ab-91df-42f0-a281-4bc3969e96c3/view-source).

This accomplishes at least two things:

1. It notifies future visitors, who might be confused by the answer, and clarifies where the answer came from. (It might even ward off downvotes from people who otherwise wouldn't notice the reason for the apparent disconnect between question and answer.)
2. More importantly, by leaving a comment under the answer, the individual who wrote the answer will get a notification in their inbox. That will alert them to the situation, and they can decide whether they want to edit their answer to fit the revised question, leave an additional comment. or delete their now-defunct answer altogether.

I would recommend this solution over adding a couple words like *Post Script*. The comment fully explains the situation, whereas a label like *Post Script* could easily confuse anyone who hasn't read this meta question yet.

Comment: As a footnote, if the person decides to modify their answer to fit the revised question, they can then flag the comment as obsolete, so that a moderator can delete the comment.